# Chrome bookmarks become invisible on subfolder hover

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

This morning I cleaned up some of my Chrome bookmarks. Now when I click a folder on the bookmarks bar and hover over a subfolder, all the bookmarks in the clicked folder become invisible (including the one I'm hovering over). Here's a screenshot of this very annoying weirdness:

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this? (Based on my fruitless Google searches, I seem to be the only person on the Internet experiencing this problem.)

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: @user3220123 I found a workaround:

1. Open settings
2. Click 'Show advanced settings...'
3. Scroll to the 'System' section at the very bottom
4. Uncheck the 'Use hardware acceleration when available' box
5. Restart Chrome (required). I'm going to check for updates to my graphic driver.

Comment: Updating my graphics driver made no difference, so I filed a bug in the Chromium project: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336493

Answer (score 0):

I had the same annoying problem, I fixed it by unchecking the hardware acceleration in Chrome settings, as stated by Alien Bishop in the comments above.